# Print screen key stroke event not functioning in IE10 or 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have used below JavaScript function to capture print screen keystroke and URL to log it in my DB (DB part is hard coded in code behind file). This JavaScript function is working fine in Chrome and Firefox without any issues but not in IE 10 or 11. I have applied same logic for 2 web pages in the website where 2nd page will open as a popup window when click on a link in page 1.

Note: In IE 10 or 11, this JavaScript function works fine for 1 time in page 1 when page is loaded but in 2nd page when I press print screen button there is no response and when I press other buttons event is raising.

Now I'm so confused since the same function is working fine in other browsers and not in IE. DO I need to make any changes related to IE?

```
<script src="/_resources/jquery.1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).keyup(function (event) {

            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            var sPath = window.location.href;
            var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 2);

            if (keycode == '44') {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Products.aspx/InsertData",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ pagename: sPath }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (result) {

                    }
                });


            }

        });
    });

   </script>
```

Comment: Still most of the users of this website uses IE as default browsers.

Comment: Does IE indicate an error when the key is pressed?  Or is the keyup event not firing at all after the first time?

Comment: Hi Lorek, As mentioned above in page 1 print screen keyup event is firing for 1st time and it become unresponsive after that. But still other key events are firing that page.

Comment: In page 2 not even for the 1st time print screen keyup event is not firing though other key events are firing.